# Why do Jasmine expect().toHaveBeenCalled assertions fail without wrapper function

Tags: angular, jasmine

If I have a subscription like this

```
this.submit$.subscribe(this.handleSubmit);
```

And I test it like this

```
it('should set up a subscription on submit$', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'handleSubmit');
  component.submits$.next(data);
  expect(component.handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(component.handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(data);
});
```

I get this error:

`Error: Expected spy handleSubmit to have been called once. It was called 0 times.`

If I instead make a new anonymous function for the subscribe callback, everything works properly:

```
this.submit$.subscribe(data => this.handleSubmit(data));
```

Why do I need to create this extra function for the tests to pass?

Comment: Is it because the subscription is already tied to the true component.handleSubmit by the time I create the spy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.submit$.subscribe(this.handleSubmit)` was in the constructor. By the time I had called `spyOn(component, 'handleSubmit')` in the test, the constructor had already been called and the subscription was already created. Even though I now had a spy on `handleSubmit`, the subscription is always going to call the original `handleSubmit`.

When using an anonymous function as the subscribe callback `this.submit$.subscribe(data => this.handleSubmit(data))` the subscription is tied to that anonymous function. This gives me the ability to spy on `handleSubmit` before it's called since the anonymous function won't be called until submit$ emits.

I solved this by moving `this.submit$.subscribe(this.handleSubmit);` to ngOnInit so that I can control when the subscription is created.